# WholeStageCodegen’s min duration larger than the query duration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-ui

I found in the spark ui, the duration of the min time of the WholeStageCodegen part larger than the duration of the query.
I think that does not make sense right?

Now, I want to examine the where does those total, min, max were calculated in the Spark 3.1 version.

Could anyone give me some guidance?
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a larger screenshot  with what's above the "6s" info? Also keep in mind that the time is distributed among several workers.

Comment: Yes, but above the 6s, there is just shows the submitted time